# Counting seconds in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, count

I'm trying to make a simple applet that will just count out seconds.
For some reason, my code starts at "2" and counts in even numbers.
After looking closely at my code, I can't see why it would do this! Could someone help me out please?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable {

    int seconds= 0;
    public void init() {
        setSize(50, 50);
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(seconds));
                seconds= seconds +1;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   

    public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(String.valueOf(seconds), 25, 25);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both threads are updating (near enough) the same time, so your counter is been incremented twice each 1000 milliseconds

Comment: Hm... how would I go about fixing this?
Thanks

Comment: You created 2 threads. They updated the counter almost at the same time. So you see even numbers. Try use only one thread?

Comment: Why is there a Thread.sleep(17)? By the way, if you want the best solution, Thread.sleep() should be avoided in favor of a Timer object instead.

Comment: Use a javax.swing.Timer or use a single thread instead of two

Comment: As a possible [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356583/counter-on-jframe/24356863#24356863)

Comment: the Thread.sleep refreshes everything every 17 milliseconds, making it 50FPS. I think... that's just what I was told to do in my tutorial class. I get errors if I take it out :/

Also, I've tried using a timer object for a few days now, but I have a lot of trouble painting the time. I can easily print it in the console though. If you know how to paint it, could you please check my other question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739069/implementing-a-timer-into-an-applet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you started two threads that increment the same variable within the same duration. That's why it counts twice.

Secondly, instead of incrementing after thread sleep, you better use this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(true){
    try {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(seconds));
        seconds= (System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000;
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change a few things. For one, you should be extending [`JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html). You only need one `Thread`, should store the startTime and calculate the number of seconds, you should clear your drawing area between refreshes. When I change it like so, it works here -

```
public class Main extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
  private long startTime = 0;

  final int width = 100;
  final int height = 100;

  public void init() {
    setSize(width, height);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
    t.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    long seconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000l;
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g.drawString(String.valueOf(seconds), 25, 25);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    long seconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000l;
    System.out.println(seconds);
    repaint();
  }
}
```

Comment: Several things leap out of. 1- You should avoid extending from top level containers, such `JApplet` and instead extend from something like `JPanel`; 2- If you're going to utilise Swing based API, you should use `javax.swing.Timer`; 3- You should be calling `super.paint` as paint does a lot of important jobs that could otherwise jeopardise output of the appley

Comment: So many people have told me to use JApplet. I definitely will next time. Unfortunately, this timer is part of a game I am programming based off a tutorial that I watched, where, for some reason, they used applet instead. I think it's probably too late to go and reprogram everything to JApplet now, so I am trying to find a way of making the timer in Applet.

Comment: Unless it's easy to convert from Applet to JApplet? I have no idea, I'm brand new to this whole world :p

Comment: @MadProgrammer Edited. I was trying to based it on OP's existing code, and I was a bit lazy with it. That should address everything but point 1, and while I agree in general I think JApplet is certainly better then Applet.

Comment: Top level container refer to Applets as well ;) and I don't have enough context to suggest otherwise, but I would also recommend Swing based components over AWT where possible as well